# How to add camera preview live filters like Retrica?

Tags: android, android-camera, gpuimage

I'm creating app with live camera filters and now I don't know what to do. How do Retrica live filters work?
I tried GPUImage but its is fps too slow - https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage/issues/40.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should write your own Camera.Renderer and use OpenGL ES shaders. Also, you can write any needed filter with OpenGL shaders language (GLSL) and put it in your code or raw folder.

Comment: any sample code?